# rapidjson : Extract a parameter from JsonObject using rapidjson

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I have a jsonObject that looks like

```
{"Types":[{"Mtype":"text/plain","time":"Thus:24:32:02"},{"MtypeSec":"text/plain","time":"Thus:24:32:02"}]}
```

I wanted to know how I can extract Mtype and time ? is the `Types` a jsonArray ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `Types` is an array, but arrays are a subclass of `Object` so that is why `IsObject()` returns true. You should call `IsArray()` on it to see if it is an array.

The correct syntax would be `document["Types"][0]["Mtype"].GetString()`, or you can iterate over it with the following:

```
for (SizeType i = 0; i < document["Types"].Size(); i++){
    std::string strval;
    if(document["Types"][i].hasMember("Mtype")){
        strval = document["Types"][i]["Mtype"].GetString();
    } else if(document["Types"][i].hasMember("mtypeSec")){
        strval = document["Types"][i]["mtypeSec"].GetString();
    } else if(document["Types"][i].hasMember("time")){
        strval = document["Types"][i]["time"].GetString();
    } else if(/*other member test*/){
        //do something with other member
    } else {
        //base case, member not in the list of useful members
    }
    //do something useful with strval
    ....
}
```